# ajax callback method for jQuery.load

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use jQuery.load in my site to loading some of content and in some place I use $.get to load Html to container because I need response data. Now I have a problem because i want to overload method ajaxSuccess to do action for all uses of load/get/post etc. but it doesn't work with load ( i check data parameter to find my special flag in response) so is possible change result of jQuery.load in any of ajax methods? do I change all load to get/post?

Comment: Please post your code in your question so we can see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
 $('#wrap').load('elements/main.html', function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
     if (textStatus == "success") {
          alert(1);
         console.log(responseText);
         /*Do something here*/
    }
    if (textStatus == "error") {
         alert(0);
         console.log(responseText);
         /*Do something here*/
    }
 });
```

For global load success method use this:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(data) {
    if(data != ''){
        console.log(data);  
    }
});
```

But it wil also affect your other `ajax` calls. :(

Comment: it is any universal method to do this? because I have a lot of place where I use load